# My wi-fi doesn't connect half the time using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, netgear

I'm new to Ubuntu so forgive me if I'm not providing enough information. My issue is that half of the time my Wireless is unable to connect and keeps prompting me for the Network Password. If I turn off the adapter from Network Manager and try again, half of the time it works.

I'm using a Netgear A7000 USB Wi-Fi Adapter on my desktop and my router is a Netgear AC1900. My driver came from https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? Is it a router issue or a driver issue or an OS thing? The Wireless adapter is always able to recognize the open networks it just fails to connect sometimes.

Here's what I get when I run `lshw -class network`

```
description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlxbca5119becd6
       serial: bc:a5:11:9b:ec:d6
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=8814au driverversion=5.8.0-38-generic ip=192.168.1.5 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

This is my wireless card `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9054 NetGear, Inc. A7000`

Nothing is blocked:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Looking at the Network Manager logs gives me this which is the errors that show up multiple times:

```
Jan 20 13:28:06 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167286.4494] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jan 20 13:28:16 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167296.4592] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 20 13:28:22 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167302.8353] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167307.2616] device (wlxbca5119becd6): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167307.2617] device (wlxbca5119becd6): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167307.2620] sup-iface[0x55c4b5225210,wlxbca5119becd6]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167307.2632] device (wlxbca5119becd6): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167307.9629] sup-iface[0x55c4b5225210,wlxbca5119becd6]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167307.9632] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167307.9647] sup-iface[0x55c4b5225210,wlxbca5119becd6]: connection disconnected (reason 1)
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167307.9650] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 20 13:28:27 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167307.9700] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6369] device (wlxbca5119becd6): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6375] device (wlxbca5119becd6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6378] device (wlxbca5119becd6): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Internet' has security, and secrets exist.  >
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6379] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Internet'
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6379] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6379] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6379] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6380] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 20 13:28:29 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167309.6380] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 20 13:28:34 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167314.3684] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Jan 20 13:28:36 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167316.0469] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 20 13:28:36 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167316.0523] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jan 20 13:28:46 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167326.8375] sup-iface[0x55c4b5225210,wlxbca5119becd6]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 20 13:28:46 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167326.8420] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 20 13:28:46 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167326.8429] device (wlxbca5119becd6): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Jan 20 13:28:46 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167326.8431] device (wlxbca5119becd6): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-st>
Jan 20 13:28:46 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167326.9420] device (wlxbca5119becd6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 20 13:28:58 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167338.8063] device (wlxbca5119becd6): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Jan 20 13:28:58 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167338.8063] device (wlxbca5119becd6): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'manag>
Jan 20 13:28:58 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1611167338.8069] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 20 13:28:58 desktop NetworkManager[739]: <warn>  [1611167338.8081] device (wlxbca5119becd6): Activation: failed for connection 'Internet'
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for the command! I updated the post with logs